# real polymorphism in embed relations in mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongoid, polymorphic-associations

Using Mongoid3, I'm trying to add polymorphism to my embedded relations.

I have a class `Item` that must **embed_one** object containing my informations.
The deal is that :
 - my object's type can be one of those : `Calendar`, `Sticker`, `Picture`;
 - regardless my object's type, I want to access it by a unique 'key' : *detail*
e.g. :

```
pry> my_item1.detail  
=> `<Picture _id: 1234>`  
pry> my_item2.detail  
=> `<Sticker _id: 8964>`
pry>
```

First, I tried using the keywords **as** and **polymorphic** like described here: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/902
e.g. :

```
class Item
    include Mongoid::Document
    embeds_one  :detail, as: :item_slot
end

class Picture
    include Mongoid::Document
    embedded_in :item_slot, polymorphic: true
end

class Calendar
    include Mongoid::Document
    embedded_in :item_slot, polymorphic: true
end

class Sticker
    include Mongoid::Document
    embedded_in :item_slot, polymorphic: true
end
```

Then I'm trying to access to my *detail* but unhappily, I got this message error :

```
pry(main)> i = Item.new
pry(main)> i.detail
=> nil
pry(main)> i.detail = Picture.find('50b864').dup
pry(main)> i.save
=> true
pry(main)> i = Item.find i._id
pry(main)> i.detail
NameError: uninitialized constant Detail
from /home/jg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
```

It says mongoid didn't find any `.detail` into my `item`. Why not.

Then, I found this topic [mongoid polymorphic association error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567481/mongoid-polymorphic-association-error) telling to add **class_name**. So I updated my code like so :

```
class Item  
    include Mongoid::Document
    embeds_one  :detail, class_name: "Picture", class_name: "Calendar", class_name: "Sticker"
end
```

Let's try:

```
pry(main)> i.detail = Picture.find('50b864').dup
pry(main)> i.save
=> true
pry(main)> i = Item.find i._id
pry(main)> i.detail
=> #<Sticker _id: 52961d>
```

That's embarrassing because I was expecting to get a `Picture`, not a `Sticker` *(it has my picture's values inside)*. (The result is the same if I put each different **class_name** value on new lines.)

For my third try, I used [Custom Relation Names](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#common) like so :

```
class Item  
    include Mongoid::Document
    embeds_one  :detail, class_name: "Picture", class_name: "Calendar", class_name: "Sticker", inverse_of: :item_slot
end

class Picture # for Calendar and Sticker too ofc
    include Mongoid::Document
    embedded_in :item_slot, polymorphic: true, inverse_of: :detail
end
```

But it gave me a Sticker too.
I even tried :

```
class Item  
    include Mongoid::Document
    embeds_one  :detail, inverse_of: :item_slot
end
```

But it send me again the NameError seen previously.

My last try was to use inheritance :

```
class Item  
    include Mongoid::Document
    embeds_one :detail
end

class Detail
    include Mongoid::Document
    embedded_in :item
end

# Same again for Calendar and Sticker
class Picture < Detail
    ... # regular other fields
end
```

But it gives me awful messages when lunching *pry*  for sticker.rb and calendar.rb

```
 DEVEL -  Failed to load .../models/sticker.rb; removing partially defined constants
 DEVEL -  Problem while loading .../models/sticker.rb: uninitialized constant Detail
```

I have no more idea..
==> Have anyone a tips ?

**EDIT** :
It would be nice to have an equivalent to `Hash[e.attributes]` like here [Extract `Moped::BSON::Document` attributes in Ruby hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006259/how-to-convert-mopedbsondocument-to-ruby-hash) and then do like so :

```
class Item
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :detail
end
```

that keep my `Picture`, `Calendar` and `Sticker` as class instances (because I have different methods for each to apply after saving).

JG

**EDIT: Alternative way**
edit 08/08/2014, split that part as the answer of that topic.

Comment: This issue is really bad, and I think you deserve some credit for this post. You should add the 'edit' you made as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use inheritance both with polymorphic relation
Here you go:

> base class

```
class Resource
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embedded_in :resoursable, polymorphic: true
end
```

> childs

```
class Photo < Resource
  field :width,  type: Integer
  field :height,  type: Integer
end

class Video < Resource
  field :url,  type: String
end
```

> embedding

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_one :media, as: :resoursable, class_name: 'Resource'
end
```

> code

```
p = Post.last
resource = Photo.new
p.media = resource
p.save!
```

Comment: I didn't tested yet. But what you propose is really close to the test I mention before the edits (Ctrl+F "My last try was to use inheritance"). Sure it solves the starting error messages, but does it give you what you really query ? I mean, `p.media` will certainly give you `Resource` instead of a `Photo`.

Comment: At first it's embedding so the querying is different. But in console if i do p = Post.last and then p.media -- it prints Photo object to console

Comment: what prints `p.media.class.to_s` ? In my example, it also returns all the informations, but the classname is wrong

Comment: It returns Photo for me. I'm using mongodb 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that's not possible yet in Mongoid github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2560 . So, I do something like that:

```
class Item
    include Mongoid::Document
    embeds_one :picture
    embeds_one :sticker
    embeds_one :calendar

    # attributes to the right field the document to embed
    def detail=(my_object)
        send("#{my_object.class.to_s.downcase}=", my_object)
        detail
    end

    # returns the embedded object
    def detail
        picture || sticker || calendar
    end
end

# Similar to Sticker and Calendar
class Picture
    embedded_in :item
end
```

If someone has a better answer, I take it !
howsoever, hope it will help the next one in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Today I have encountered a similar problem, I found Mongoid4 have solved the question.

```rb
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :detail
end
```

parent class

```rb
class Detail
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :item
end
```

child class

```rb
class Picture < Detail
end

class Sticker < Detail
end

class Calendar < Detail
end
```

```rb
i = Item.new
i.detail = Picture.new
i.save
i.detail

#<Picture _id: 6b78d7866289a63078, _type: "Picture">
```